# How to install Pylucene locally without root access on a server?

Tags: makefile, lucene, pylucene

recently I try to install pylucene on a server in my own home directory because I have no root priviledge.

Now I have successfully installed **ant** and **JCC** locally on CentOS under my own home directory. The directory of JCC is "/home/myname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages"

I have also successfully "make" under the pylucene directory, but when "make install" it shows that it tries to move some files into the directory " /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/" which I have no permission to access it.

I do changed the Makefile several places as required.

In the comments it says:

```
PREFIX: where programs are normally installed on your system (Unix).
```

But there is no variable named as PREFIX

I changed

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr
ANT=/home/myname/packages/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin/ant
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python2.6
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc.__main__
NUM_FILES=8
```

When I read the Makefile I do not see a environmental variable that controls the installing directory or I miss something ?

### SOlved

Thank you guys. I have figured it out.
I just move the builded “lucene”  folder directly to my local "site-packages" directory and it works.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem on my machine where I dont have root privileges. It seems it wants to install PyLucene to the default site-package folder (where I do not have privileges). How did you define a custom local site-package folder ?

Comment: I made a local site-package that I added in the PYTHONPATH. at which point did you move the builded folder to your local site-package :)?

Answer (score 1):

`INSTALL_OPT=--prefix <path>`

The [homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/pylucene.rb) has an example of this.